# How to pagination with node.js or javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I Have this data ,

i have this data, and i want to fix my codes

```
        const { page, per_page } = request.all();

        const array_totals = [3, 5];
        const total = 8;
        // const page = 1;
        // const per_page = 4;

        const list_data = [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        ];

        const paginate = (_poge, per_page, data) => {
            const page = parseInt(_poge);
            const limit = parseInt(per_page);
            const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
            const endIndex = page * limit;

            return data.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        };

        const calculatePagesCount = (pageSize, totalCount) => {
            // we suppose that if we have 0 items we want 1 empty page
            return totalCount < pageSize ? 1 : Math.ceil(totalCount / pageSize);
        };

        const data_paginate = (page, per_page) => {
            const sr = [0, 1];
            const last_page = calculatePagesCount(per_page, total);

            let ret_data = [];
            let _data = [];
            let data_read = [];

            for (let index = 0; index < sr.length; index++) {
                /*
                 * check array pertama apakah sudah last page
                 */
                const max_page_item = calculatePagesCount(
                    per_page,
                    list_data[index].length
                );

                if (per_page < list_data[index].length) {
                    _data = paginate(page, per_page, list_data[index]);
                    ret_data = [...ret_data, ..._data];
                }


                if (page === (max_page_item + index) && ret_data.length <= per_page) {
                    _data = paginate(page, per_page, list_data[index]);
                    ret_data = [...ret_data, ..._data];
                }

                if (index > 0 && per_page > list_data[index - 1].length && ret_data.length <= per_page) {
                    _data = paginate(
                        page,
                        per_page - list_data[index - 1].length,
                        list_data[index]
                    );
                    ret_data = [...ret_data, ..._data];
                }

                if (ret_data.length === per_page) break

            }

            return {
                data: ret_data,
                page,
                per_page,
                last_page,
                total,
            };
        };
        // console.log(data_paginate(1, 5))
        const data = data_paginate(Number(page), Number(per_page))
        return data
```

`const data = data_paginate(Number(page), Number(per_page))`

But my code is not producing what I expected, when i tested to
`console.log(data_paginate(2, 3)`

and how to fix my code brother ?

when I execute the code console.log(data_paginate(3, 2))

`{     "data": [        8     ],     "page": 3,     "per_page": 2,     "last_page": 4,     "total": 8 }`

which the code should generate

`{     "data": [        5,6     ],     "page": 3,     "per_page": 2,     "last_page": 4,     "total": 8 }`

Answer (score 0):

First, flatten `list_data` using [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and then use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the chunk of data you'd like.

We'd use `per_page * (page - 1)` as the start parameter and `per_page * page` as the end parameter. This is because for our `.slice()` to work as I believe you'd like, `0` would be the first page number that multiplies `per_page` but it seems like the parameter to set the first page when calling `data_paginate` is `1`.

```js
const {
  page,
  per_page
} = { page: 3, per_page: 2 };

const array_totals = [3, 5];
const total = 8;
// const page = 1;
// const per_page = 4;

const list_data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
];

const calculatePagesCount = (pageSize, totalCount) => {
  // we suppose that if we have 0 items we want 1 empty page
  return totalCount < pageSize ? 1 : Math.ceil(totalCount / pageSize);
};

const data_paginate = (thisPage, thisPerPage) => {
  return {
    data: list_data.flat().slice(thisPerPage * (thisPage - 1), thisPerPage * thisPage),
    page: thisPage,
    per_page: thisPerPage,
    last_page: calculatePagesCount(thisPerPage, total),
    total,
  };
};
// console.log(data_paginate(1, 5))
const data = data_paginate(Number(page), Number(per_page))
console.log(data);
```

Comment: your answer does not answer our question

Comment: I believe the answer should answer your question, "how to fix my code" – I shown you how to fix your code.

Comment: is it possible if not using flat array ?

Comment: The array value of `list_data` is not flat as per your original question, but I converted it to a flat array using `.flat()` as per the answer.

Comment: because in reality we are taking the array data from the api server, and it is also impossible if we use a flat array .. it will burden our server's performance

Comment: The flattening happens *after* the array data has been received, the `.flat()` call will flatten any multidimensional array data your receive.